# nginx rewrite wp default /?page_id=10 to /my-cool-page

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I've got a friend whose WP site is using the default /?page_id=xx permalink structure. I have been trying to create a nginx rewrite to convert the links to a post_name scheme.

There are dozens of pages that need to be redirected so I added a file (snippets/rewrite.conf ) to handle the rewrites and included it in my nginx.conf file:

When I have the permalinks set to post_name, this works (indicating that rewrite is enabled):
    `rewrite https://example.com/features https://example.com/my-cool-page permanent;`

I've tried every which way to make this work for /?page_id=xx permalink structure but it doesn't want to redirect.

When I have the permalinks set to default, this doesn't work:
    `rewrite ^/?page_id=45 /?page_id=60 permanent;`

I've been googling for hours and I just can't find a solution. What is the correct way to form the rewrite.

Ubuntu 16.04
Nginx 1.10.0
MariaDB 10.1.14
PHP 7.0.4

Comment: I also tried this without success: `rewrite ^/(.*)page_id=45 https://example.com/?page_id=60 permanent;`

Comment: Isnt the "URL permalink structure" just an option in Wordpress?

Comment: I want to throw a 301 redirect to requests for /?page =xx to /whatever-my-cool-page